# Javascript in Adobe DC

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, listbox, adobe

I created a list box with a long list of options. However, I would only like the selected options to appear on the printed document.

Can somebody help me correct this code?

```
try {
  // assume value is an array
  event.value = this.getField('List Box1').value.join(', ');
} catch(e) {
  // trap error when not an array - so use value only
  event.value = this.getField('List Box1').value;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't code and don't understand matters regarding it that is why I am seeking help for a form that I am making. I am sorry if my response bothered you.

Comment: Thank you so much Rory McCrossan. I appreciate your help.